# Getting error logs in console of Tomcat while using MongoDB with Java MongoDB driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, timertask

I am new to MongoDB with Java, getting following logs while running my webapp in console of tomcat repeatedly. I am using the following code to access MongoDB with java. I wrote mongodb connection code in my **TimerTask** and inserting a document in TimerTask's run method, I don't know whether this error is because of mongodb or something else.

```
class RequestTask extends TimerTask {           
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + dbURL);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);

/*
 * To connect database, specify the database name, if the
 * database doesn't exist then MongoDB creates it automatically.
 */
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
// System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");

MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(collectionName);

public void run() {
    try {
            // Other code
            mongoCollection.insertOne(jsonDocument);
            // Other code   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + "During  Collection Insert : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

And creating instance of above RequestTask and scheduling it using scheduledExecutorService's scheduleAtFixedRate method

```
timerTask = new RequestTask();
timer = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0,
                                    pollingInterval.getPollingInterval(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Error logs in Tomcat Console as:

```
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4508 ms
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/qxpsmonitor] has started
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [qxpsmonitor] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='58ad37d09ad1689fa0249f07', description='null'}-null:27017] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1248)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
 java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
 com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186)
 com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
 com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
 com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [qxpsmonitor] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Feb 22, 2017 12:33:56 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Comment: How many times did you call insertOne?

Comment: I am using scheduledExecutorService's scheduleAtFixedRate method to execute my run method After each 30 seconds `timer = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0,30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: It doesn't work even in the first time?

Comment: It's working but also showing error

Comment: Maybe you're creating too many threads or maybe your threads are not returning. That'd be my guess

Comment: @israel.zinc yeah I think somewhere your guess is right. So If your guess is right then what should I do for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136355/discussion-between-rohit-luthra-and-israel-zinc).